# Where can one find reliable, canonical (geo) data for Germany PLZ (postal zip codes)?

Tags: germany, postal-code

Does anyone know please: Is there a reliable, "official" list of postal codes and cities (additional data like lat/long welcome) in Germany, available for download?  At a minimum, I'm looking for the PLZ (5 digit zip code) and city/location name.

Answer (score 3):

try this one for postal codes: http://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/downloads?download=plz-gebiete.shp.zip
Concerning the cities, I would prefer Geofabrik: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html

Please note that PLZ-geodata is the property of Deutsche Post, changing every year its geometries (but only little parts of it) and selling it at a price - so you cannot be sure downloading "canoninal" geodata.

spiralhirn

Answer (score 1):

Another resource: http://www.manfrin-it.com/postleitzahlen/plz.html

> [DE] Wir haben die Postleitzahlen mit Orts-, Kreis- und Länderzuordnung per SQL OpenGeoDB ausgelesen und stellen diese in den Formaten für Excel und FileMaker sowie als Text-Datei zum Download bereit.
>
> [EN] We select the postcodes with local, district and country specification from SQL OpenGeoDB and provide these in formats for Excel and FileMaker, as well as a text file to download.